# Check if a string is sorted in javascript

Tags: javascript

please i want to check if this string is sorted?

`var myBucket = "1D2D1W2W1M2M3M4M5M6M9M1Y18M2Y30M3Y4Y5Y6Y8Y10Y15Y20Y25Y30Y1D2D1W2W1M2M3M4M5M6M9M1Y18M2Y30M3Y4Y5Y6Y8Y10Y15Y20Y25Y30Y";`

---

```
1D=One Day 2D=2 Day ...
1W=1 Week 
1M=1 Months 18M=18 Months
1Y=1 years
like 1D<2D<1W<3W<1M<10M<1Y<18M<2Y ...
```

How can i check this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Brb going to do your homework for you

Comment: not the greatest way to start in the community. Please study the rules about posting a question

Comment: In all seriousness, one possible solution is to iterate over the string. Grab the number then the letter. Convert the number(s) to an integer. Using the letter and the number, produce the number of days (example 1Y = 365D). Then do a comparison to the current item to the previous item (except on first iteration of course).

Comment: I'd start with calling `var parts = myBucket.match(/^(\d+)(\w+)([\w\d]*)$/);` in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to match a number and the length indicator. Then loop over with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and split the part into number and length indicator. With a hash table for the length, you could calculate the length and test it with the last value before.

If greater, then proceed, else leave the loop and get `false`.

If the loop iterates over all elements, and the callback returns `true`, then it return `true`.

```js
var myBucket = '1D2D1W2W1M2M3M4M5M6M9M1Y18M2Y30M3Y4Y5Y6Y8Y10Y15Y20Y25Y30Y1D2D1W2W1M2M3M4M5M6M9M1Y18M2Y30M3Y4Y5Y6Y8Y10Y15Y20Y25Y30Y',
    values = { D: 1, W: 7, M: 30, Y: 365 },
    result = myBucket.match(/\d+[DWMY]/g).every(function (a, i) {
        var p = a.split(/(?=[DWMY])/),
            value = p[0] * (values[p[1]] || 0);
        if (value > this.last) {
            this.last = value;
            return true;
        }
    }, { last: -Infinity });

console.log(result);
```